# How to keep beacon in pairing mode until it comes out of range for android?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, ibeacon

I am developing an application to communicate with beacon. It display all the names of beacons, I have to pair & connect to beacon on onclick event.I need to keep beacon in connecting mode until it goes out of range. But in my case it disconnects after certain amount of time.Please tell me how to keep beacon in pairing mode until it comes out of range.

Below is my code for pairing beacon to android app.

```
 private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {
        Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
        method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is common for Android Bluetooth LE connections to disconnect before you are finished communicating, so you must build logic into your app to handle these disconnect events and retry the connection as needed.

If you Bluetooth LE beacon is exiting connectable mode before you can do this, then you must somehow extend the time it is in this mode.  How you do this is (if it is possible at all) is manufacturer-specific, so you'll have to consult your beacon manufacturer's documentation on how you put the beacon into configurable mode.

Comment: We are testing beacons with ATMEL smart connect  application which is present in playstore. In that application when we send pair request on click event it get paired and  stays in pairing state ,after back press event it will disconnect . In my case It will disconnect after fraction of seconds.